# how to send crashing report on debug on google analytics from android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to send crashing report manually. So before publishing apk, I want to test it. But when app is crashed, tracker send the data but there is no changes on crash report webpage on play developer console. How can i test it ?

```
     //      tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    mExceptionParser = new StandardExceptionParser(getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList());
    analytics.setDryRun(true);
    analytics.setAppOptOut(BuildConfig.DEBUG);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                    .setDescription(
                            new StandardExceptionParser(getApplicationContext(), null)
                                    .getDescription(t.getName(), e))
                    .setFatal(true)
                    .build());

            analytics.dispatchLocalHits();


            DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext()
                    .getApplicationContext().getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics();
            if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW
                    || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                System.exit(0);

            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        main.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                if (activity != null)
                    activity.finish();
            }

            System.exit(0);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    //
    //                Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler googleException = new      ExceptionReporter(
    //                        tracker,
    //                        null,
   //                        getApplicationContext());
     //                googleException.uncaughtException(t,e);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "crashlytics" also. I am using it in all of my apps. Here is the link - https://try.crashlytics.com/. Hope it will help you.